# curl and wget ignoring JavaScript in website source

Tags: javascript, php, curl, printing

I want to monitor the fill level of my ink cartridges of my wireless printer via PHP, but I was unable to find the fitting value over SNMP. That's why I wanted to fetch the website of the integrated webserver because when I visit the site, the fill level is shown.

However when I fetch the site via curl or wget the important part is missing, the values are stored inside the JavaScript in the header of the file. This is how it should look like:

```
<!-- contain metaheader and html includes -->
   <META HTTP-EQUIV=refresh CONTENT= > <!-- contain metaheader to refresh this page --> 
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      <!-- add in specific javascript functions here    

      var blackink=30;
      var blackInkStatusImage="./gif/icon_status_normal.gif";
      var blackInkCartridgeString="Black Print Cartridge";

      var colorink=20;
      var colorInkStatusImage="./gif/icon_status_normal.gif";
      var colorInkCartridgeString="Tri-color Print Cartridge";

      -->
   </script>
<!-- specific html head page -->
```

But the part between the first and last line is missing in the curl output. Any idea why? Do I have to simulate a user agent or something like that? Printer model is an HP DeskJet F4580.

Comment: Yes, you need to simulate a user agent. `curl` and `wget` just download the contents, they don't have Javascript engines.

Comment: Look for something called `Mechanize`.

Comment: `I want to monitor the fill level of my ink cartridges of my wireless printer via PHP` can I just point out how lazy that sounds? And how much is the entire thing overengineered? I LOVE IT! I'm guilty of this myself - I'd gladly write a script that is ran as a cron job against something and spend hours automating a trivial process that will save me, perhaps, a minute at a time. It makes me feel like [a god](https://xkcd.com/676/)

Comment: `wget -p  URL` should fetch the relevant files including the JS &CSS, although you'll likely have to correct the path to them in the fetched HTML

Comment: Or., since the javascript is inline, perhaps 
. ` $blob = file_get_contents_utf8($URL);`

Comment: @vlaz indeed, it is a bit overengineered. but wait until you see my automatic plant watering... :D
However Mechanize worked fine, but is a bit difficult to setup. The easiest way was with file_get_contents, thanks @DuaneLortie!